# Freeing allocated space by callee function on caller in assembly (att)

Tags: assembly, att

I am new at this, so bear with me! ;)

I am trying to return a string on assembler. I have the string on the stack, properly terminated.

then I `movl %esp` to `%eax` and return the function. 
My thought was to call it from a c function and use this assembler function like this:

```
extern char* getthestring (void);

int main ()
{
char *m;
m=getthestring();
printf ("The string is %s", *m);
free (m);
return 0;
}
```

I'm getting segmentation fault errors, and I can't debug it, as gdb gives me this:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000001 in ?? ()
```

Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: You shouldn't be returning a pointer to a local variable. Also, you can only use `free` to free memory allocated from the heap using `malloc` and friends.

Comment: Yes, I kinda suspected this was the problem. I need to solve an assignment, and wanted to create a separate function for that. Since I believe allocating heap memory would require another function not written by me - which is forbidden by the assignment - I guess I will have to write it all on one single function.

Answer (score 0):

As @jester pointed out, I am trying to return local variables, which is a no-go.